# Ionic 3 - Splash screen hides on home button press

Tags: splash-screen, ionic3

I am developing an app in ionic 3.
Splash screen plugin is installed & it works perfectly in normal case.
But during splash if I press home or recent button in android & come back again then splash doesn't show again. Only white screen is there until page load.

Preferences for splash:

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="70000"/>
```

Ionic Info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

Comment: you have `SplashShowOnlyFirstTime` to `false`, so splash will show every-time app launch. Also there `AutoHideSplashScreen` to `false` that mean you are programmatically hiding splash. can you post `app.component.ts`  code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These was problem in plugin. In onPause splash was removed. I removed that code.

Now onPause look like:

```
@Override
public void onPause(boolean multitasking) {
    if (HAS_BUILT_IN_SPLASH_SCREEN) {
        return;
    }
}
```